# Which should be used when naming a variable in Objective C, "http" or "HTTP" prefix?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, design-patterns

Which is better naming convention for this instance variable,

`int httpRequestId;` (normal convention)

or

`int HTTPRequestId;` (Apple always uses HTTP rather than Http in it's class name, so HTTP is a like a keyword?so should be capital always).

Answer (score 5):

Based on Apple's coding styles for Objective C,

> Private instance variables names start with lower-case letters, but are internally capitalized wherever a new word appears. (page 3 of the [manual](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000082.php))

which is basically a form of Camel case (or lower Camel case if you feel picky).

Based on the standard, `HTTPRequestId` violates the naming conventions. Event though `HTTP` is an acceptable acronym for a class name (take a look at the [official list](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/APIAbbreviations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001285-BCIHCGAE)) you aren't using it as a class name but rather a variable name, so different conventions apply.

You also mentioned that in the `NSURLRequest.h` header file Apple uses `(NSData *)HTTPBody`, `(NSInputStream *)HTTPBodyStream`, and `(BOOL)HTTPShouldHandleCookies` as names. However, these are *property definitions*, they are not local variables as in your example. Property naming conventions are often the same as classes; thus using `HTTP` is proper.

`httpRequestId` is the correct name for a local variable.

Comment: Ys, that's normal convention. But apple used  - (NSData *)HTTPBody, - (NSInputStream *)HTTPBodyStream, - (BOOL)HTTPShouldHandleCookies etc in their NSURLRequest.h file, which is exception to normal method naming convention. So isn't it more appropiate HTTPRequestId if we consider apple guideline (as this is exceptional case).

Comment: If you notice, `(NSData *)HTTPBody`, `(NSInputStream *)HTTPBodyStream` `(BOOL)HTTPShouldHandleCookies` are defined as *properties*, which like in most languages follow the naming guidelines of classes. For private variables the conventions are different, thus using `httpRequestId`.

Comment: Um, no? Properties in objective-c generally use variable-like naming, not class-like naming.

Comment: @rae1n Look at the docs for UIViewController or NSLayoutConstraint.  Lowercase properties. It's just in the case of a capitalized abbreviation like `HTTP` that they capitalize it. This is a special case that cannot be generalized to all properties.

Comment: Even better, look at Apple's documentation on naming conventions: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html

Comment: @BJHomer Yes, I was just taking a look. True, my bad. However, I still believe the convention should not be applied to a private local variable. The `HTTP` in uppercase that is.

Answer (score -1):

Honestly, it doesn't really matter. Rather than being worried about naming, you should make sure everything is clear and well spaced. Unless you have a name that is really similar or close to a class or method name, you should not worry about it. This is mainly a personal choice. Do whatever you want. Just make sure you can read it.
\|˙∆˙|/

Comment: Unfortunately, it matters in this case, I need to follow the 100% correct naming here. So it's very important.